# Terraform orchestrating AWS SSO using AD Connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to orchestrate thru terraform the creation of an AD Connector and also enable SSO for my AWS Orgs. Here's an example of the terraform module I use:

```
resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "connector" {
  name       = "${var.ad_domain_name}"
  password   = "${var.ad_password}"
  size       = "${var.ad_size}"
  type       = "ADConnector"
  enable_sso = "${var.enable_sso}"
  alias      = "${var.ad_alias}"

  connect_settings {
    customer_dns_ips  = "${var.ad_dns_ips}"
    customer_username = "${var.ad_username}"
    subnet_ids        = [ "${var.ad_subnet_ids}" ]
    vpc_id            = "${var.vpc_id}"
  }
}
```

When I apply this, the AD Connector is created correctly and goes active, etc, but the SSO is not configured to use the AD Connector; SSO is still pointed to the default AWS SSO Directory. I have to manually select the Microsoft AD Directory->AD Connector to enable it.

Is it possible to fully create and configure AWS SSO to use an AD Connector via terraform or does AWS SSO with an AD Connector need to be configured manually?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Even though I would have loved to see Terraform/AWS API support, Single Sign-On FAQ page says that

```
Is there an API available for AWS SSO?

No. You can use the AWS SSO console to perform all necessary operations.
```

Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/single-sign-on/faqs/

**EDIT Apr. 2021:**

> Is there an API available for AWS SSO?
>
> **Yes**. AWS SSO provides account assignment APIs to help you automate permissions management in multi-account environments, and retrieve the permissions programmatically for audit and governance purposes.